# next-intl how do I ignore certain routes?

Tags: next.js, next-intl

I'm wondering how I disable next-intl for certain routes. Currently I have a few policy pages which I dont want to translate, but even though I dont import the translate file in `getStaticProps` nor use `useTranslate` I still get the following error spammed in my console:

```
IntlError: MISSING_MESSAGE: No messages were configured on the provider.
    at getMessagesOrError (C:\repos\gitlab\project\node_modules\use-intl\dist\use-intl.cjs.development.js:239:21)
    at C:\repos\gitlab\project\node_modules\use-intl\dist\use-intl.cjs.development.js:714:12
    at Object.useMemo (C:\repos\gitlab\project\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5124:19)
    at Object.useMemo (C:\repos\gitlab\project\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1650:21)
    at useTranslationsImpl (C:\repos\gitlab\project\node_modules\use-intl\dist\use-intl.cjs.development.js:713:31)
    at useTranslations (C:\repos\gitlab\project\node_modules\use-intl\dist\use-intl.cjs.development.js:750:10)
    at ErrorBoundaryHOC (webpack-internal:///./src/ErrorBoundary.tsx:56:73)
    at renderWithHooks (C:\repos\gitlab\project\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (C:\repos\gitlab\project\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5731:15)
    at renderElement (C:\repos\gitlab\project\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5946:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\repos\gitlab\project\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (C:\repos\gitlab\project\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
    at renderNode (C:\repos\gitlab\project\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6259:12)
    at renderChildrenArray (C:\repos\gitlab\project\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6211:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\repos\gitlab\project\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6141:7) {
  code: 'MISSING_MESSAGE',
originalMessage: 'No messages were configured on the provider.'
}
```

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68223386/disable-localization-for-a-route-i18n-in-next-js), I tried the following in `next.config.js` without any luck:

```
ignoreRoutes: [
    '/privacy-policy'
],
```